# Django: No module named models

Tags: python, django, models, importerror

`ImportError: no module named location.models` at the following line:

```
from location.models import Zipcode
```

But there is a `models.py`, an `__init__.py`, and a `Zipcode` model in an installed app called `location` in my project.

Further, the module is easily imported in the python shell using the same command. What could be the problem here? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: I'd check that you have your pythonpath set up correctly.

Comment: Would it be accessible in the python shell if it was not on the pythonpath?

Comment: You likely have two different pythonpaths in the two environments. You don't tell us anything about your setup, or indeed whether you're running the shell in a similarly configured environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your commentary @Marcin. Turns out that I had a file called `location.py` in my `views.py` folder, which was causing some kind of conflict. I renamed this file `location_view.py` and voila.

So moral of the story, I guess, is check to make sure that you dont have any name conflicts in an app when you are trying to import an app of the same name..

Comment: Ok well if you can explain better please be my guest. I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: This is why you should use relative paths when importing modules.

Comment: If anyone wants to post a more succinct answer feel free. I'm still noob status being more front-end oriented...